# I am displaying user input along with search results but i am seeing default message in text box how to remove it?

Tags: php, html

[my php code with html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU94c.png)
I am trying to display user input along with search result but some default message is appearing in search field after adding value for text field to hold the word to display along with search result

Comment: Copy and Paste your code into your post

Comment: Provide more details, show some examples. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo ((isset($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search'] : '') ?>" value="">
```

Comment: Thanks you so much Rendi !! for your response , it is working good now !!  in the above code one close bracket missed out and i have addded before php closing tag and worked out fine. Thanks a lot !!